# Pass value to a modal in jsx map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a map that render few items. How can I pass params like name of the item, id of the item etc to the modal component?

```
render(){
    return(
        <div>

            <Modal 
                isOpen={this.state.OpenDeleteModal}
                confirmationTitle={`Delete item`}
                confirmationCancel={'No'}
                confirmationSuccess={'Yes'}
                closeModal={this.closeModal}
                successModal={this.successModal}
            >
                <p className="center">Are you sure you want to delete this item?</p>
            </Modal>

            <div className="wrapper">
                {map(items, obj =>
                    <div key={obj._id} className="panel-body">
                        <div className="row">
                            <h2 className="title">{obj.name}</h2>
                            <a onClick={()=> this.setState({OpenDeleteModal:true})}>Delete</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I only can think of put the obj._id in the tag as custom attribute and when user click on delete it change the state of the selectedItem, pass it through props.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to remember for which item you have opened the modal. Something like below. Set the `selected item` when you open the modal. During delete, fetch it from state and delete it.

```
render(){
  return(
    <div>

        <Modal 
            isOpen={this.state.OpenDeleteModal}
            confirmationTitle={`Delete item`}
            confirmationCancel={'No'}
            confirmationSuccess={'Yes'}
            closeModal={this.closeModal}
            successModal={this.successModal}
        >
            <p className="center">Are you sure you want to delete this item?</p>
        </Modal>

        <div className="wrapper">
            {map(items, obj =>
                <div key={obj._id} className="panel-body">
                    <div className="row">
                        <h2 className="title">{obj.name}</h2>
                        <a onClick={()=> this.setState({OpenDeleteModal:true, selectedItem: obj._id})}>Delete</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    </div>
 )
}
```

**UPDATE**: Make sure to clear the `selectedItem` after you close the modal.

Answer (score 0):

A modal can access the state of the react component, you can store the information of the selected link in state

```
storeInformation(item) {
     this.setState({OpenDeleteModal:true,
                            selectedId: item.id
                            selectedName: item.name

                           })
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>

            <Modal 
                isOpen={this.state.OpenDeleteModal}
                confirmationTitle={`Delete item`}
                confirmationCancel={'No'}
                confirmationSuccess={'Yes'}
                closeModal={this.closeModal}
                successModal={this.successModal}
            >
                <p className="center">Are you sure you want to delete this item?</p>
                <div>Name is: {this.state.selecteName}</div>
            </Modal>

            <div className="wrapper">
                {map(items, obj =>
                    <div key={obj._id} className="panel-body">
                        <div className="row">
                            <h2 className="title">{obj.name}</h2>
                            <a onClick={()=> this.storeInformation(obj)}>Delete</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```